# Android App Widget - AsyncTask API call in update

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-widget

I want to make a simple widget on my Android Homescreen where I am able to fill in my postalcode or city, and by submitting that data, I would like to be able to update the Widget with data from an API call to Openweathermap.org.

I've made every step to make it work, but for some reason the Widget textView won't update with the data collected.

This is my main activity.

```
public class WeerManWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = WeerManWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.weer_man_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);



    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WeerManWidgetConfigureActivity.class);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, configIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnSettings, configPendingIntent);
    configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE + Integer.toString(appWidgetId));



    new GetWeatherTask(views).execute(widgetText.toString());



    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        WeerManWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
}
```

And this is the class that I use for the API call.

```
public class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private RemoteViews views;

GetWeatherTask(RemoteViews views) {
    this.views = views;
}

@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String postalCode = params[0];

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    URL url = null;
    JSONObject object = null;
    JSONArray myArray = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+postalCode+",nl&appid=XXXXX&units=metric");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String temp, response = "";
        while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response += temp;
        }

        object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        JSONObject obj = object.getJSONObject("main");
        String weatherTemp = obj.getString("temp");

        double weatherFloat = Double.parseDouble(weatherTemp);
        //weatherFloat = (weatherFloat - 273.15);

        String newTemp = String.valueOf(weatherFloat);

        return newTemp;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {

            }
        }
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.v("WeerManWidget", result);

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, result);
}
}
```

Seen in the onPostExecute in the AsyncTask, I log the results. This has the correct data. So everthing comes along nicely, but when I want to update the view with the setTextViewText, nothing happens. I am new to Android development, and am out of ideas.

Anyone care to enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

After you called the API and used:

```
views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, result);
```

You need to use the `AppWidgetManager` to update the UI.

Here is an example:

```
AppWidgetManager manager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(widgetID,views);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void updateViewHere(String parseResult){
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class));
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, parseResult);
    AppWidgetManager manager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(ids,views);
}
```

Using this approach we can update widget views.